# Why value relation doesn't work when I delete and connect reference layer?

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms, domains

I'm trying to connect reference table (domain) with data(text) to my vector layer (id's) using value relation. I have database in Oracle connected. It works fine, but when I delete the reference layer and connect it again, everything is deleted.

Do you know how to make the connection permanent? Or am I doing anything wrong when I am connecting to the database? Or there is any other function to do this connection?

[image: before]

[image: after]

Answer (score 1):

Probably it can be solved by using value map instead of value relation. But I didn't figure out how can be solved a situation with more than one conditions, because there is no expression builder.